# <pre> tag within paragraph not on separate line

Tags: html

I like how the `<pre>` tag preserves spacing, and I'm using it to display programming code. Is it possible to place it within a paragraph?

```
<p> The C++ for loop <pre> for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) </pre> is used to ... </p>
```

The problem with the above code is that the `<pre>` section is placed on its own line. I want everything to be on the same line.

Comment: Try the obvious - `pre{display:inline}` in your CSS

Comment: @JanDvorak It still starts a new line, although the text following it is placed on the same line.

Comment: then I'm afraid `pre` within `p` is invalid HTML

Comment: @JanDvorak Oh okay.. any way out in that case?

Comment: If it is, use another tag. `code` has already been suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<p style="display:inline"> The C++ for loop <pre style="display:inline"> for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) </pre> is used to ... </p>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gD6pR/)**

Or

```
<p> The C++ for loop <code> for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) </code> is used to ... </p>
```

Comment: The first version is invalid markup, and the `<pre>` tag closes the open `p` element. This cannot be changed in CSS.

Answer (score 3):

There is another tag for showing code that is `code`. I think that would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
p{
    float:left; 
}
pre{
    display:inline;
}
```

[jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/rwwVz/)

its not a good code but its working

Answer (score 0):

No, the `pre` element cannot appear inside a `p` element.

You can preserve spacing, in the sense that `pre` does so, by using the CSS declaration `white-space: pre` on any element, such as a `span` or `code` element, e.g.

```
<style>
.pre { white-space: pre; }
</style>
...
<p> The C++ for loop <code class=pre> for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) </code> is
used to ... </p>
```

The `pre` element also causes a monospace font to be used by default. The `code` element has the same effect.